# Is there a way to make my attributes using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, attributes

I wonder if there is a way for me to make my attributes (or attribute) using tensorflow model. For an example, if I want to generate following attributes array using tensorflow model

- Input : An Image
- Output : Attribute Array [image mean, image std, image entropy, sum of image edge values]

Is there a way? I know that very simple attributes such as mean, std & entropy do not have to be trained in tensorflow model. Actually they will be some custom image attributes like finding a circle shape & calculating the circularity in an image.

Thanks. Alex

Answer (score 0):

```
I found the answer myself. Answering it as I now understand the question was confusing

Machine learning algorithms require well-designed attributes. Their performance highly depend on the attributes. Normally we must write some code to read an input & calculate an attribute. My question was whether this can be done through CNN model training.

If this is feasible, I will apply a trained model for my input to calculate attributes, rather than run some code

Here is an example. This code reads image inputs & calculate image mean value by applying trained cnn model

### 

from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers

import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Reproducibility
tf.set_random_seed(777)

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# num_examples = 55000
train_dataset = mnist.train.images
# train labels
train_labels = np.mean(train_dataset, axis=1)
# num_examples = 10000
test_dataset = mnist.test.images
# test labels
test_labels = np.mean(test_dataset, axis=1)


# model build
# Here, we'll use a Sequential model with two densely connected hidden layers,
# and an output layer that returns a single, continuous value.
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[np.shape(train_dataset)[1]]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])
  #optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model


# print progress
class PrintDot(keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
    if epoch % 100 == 0: print('')
    print('.', end='')


# plot train history
def plot_TrainStatus(plot_TrainStatus):
  hist = pd.DataFrame(plot_TrainStatus.history)
  hist['epoch'] = plot_TrainStatus.epoch

  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.title('Mean Abs Error [mean]')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['mean_absolute_error'],
           label='Train Error')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['val_mean_absolute_error'],
           label = 'Val Error')
  plt.ylim([0,0.025])
  plt.legend()

  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.title('Mean Squared Error [$mean^2$]')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['mean_squared_error'],
           label='Train Error')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['val_mean_squared_error'],
           label = 'Val Error')
  plt.ylim([0,0.002])
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()


# plot test status
def plot_TestStatus(test_predictions, test_labels):
    # draw the prediction result
    plt.figure()
    a = plt.axes(aspect='equal')
    plt.scatter(test_labels, test_predictions)
    plt.xlabel('Ground Truth [mean]')
    plt.ylabel('Predictions [mean]')
    lims = [0, 0.4]
    plt.xlim(lims)
    plt.ylim(lims)
    _ = plt.plot(lims, lims)
    plt.title('Prediction vs Ground Truth (Test Data)')
    plt.legend()

    # error histogram
    plt.figure()
    error = test_predictions - test_labels
    plt.hist(error, bins=25)
    plt.xlabel("Prediction Error [mean]")
    _ = plt.ylabel("Count")

    plt.show()


# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model = build_model()

    EPOCHS = 10
    TrainStatus = model.fit(
         train_dataset, train_labels,
         epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0,
         callbacks=[PrintDot()])

    # Visualize the model's training progress using the stats stored in the history object.
    plot_TrainStatus(TrainStatus)

    loss, mae, mse = model.evaluate(test_dataset, test_labels, verbose=2)
    print("Testing set Mean Abs Error: {:5.2f}".format(mae))

    # make predictions using test data
    test_predictions = model.predict(test_dataset).flatten()

    # Visualize the model's test result
    plot_TestStatus(test_predictions, test_labels)
```